# Twilio Ruby - Unable to create record: The 'From' number +15005550006 is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

Hello i'm trying to send SMS with Twilio and Ruby. 
Everything worked fine until today when i'm trying to send sms with the error :
`Unable to create record: The 'From' number +15005550006 is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID.`

Here is my code, i don't understand why it is not working. For informations, i'm using my test credentials.

```
    def boot_twilio
    @twilio_number = ENV['TWILIO_NUMBER']
    account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
    auth_token = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
  end

  def notification(user)
    boot_twilio
    @client.messages.create(
      from: @twilio_number,
      to: user.phone
      body: "test"
    )
  end
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check again your credentials, and maybe your bills too at twilio console.

`In order to send a test sms using the Twilio test numbers, you need to make sure you are using your test credentials. From the looks of this code it seems you may be using your actual credentials.`

from: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/issues/125